# How to make a textured window shatter with the textures on the shards

Tags: texturing, uv, glass

I'm making a Minecraft animation, and my character is going to throw an object out a window, so I want it to shatter, and it's going to be a pane instead of a block. So I created new faces by creating new vertices and connecting them via edges, but when I did, the textures weren't on it. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Do you want the fragments to be uniform rectangular prisms? I don't remember, but I thought that's how it was in the game. Either way, I think the cell fracture addon will work well, just use uniform or random depending on your desired result. Then you gotta make the shards physics bodies, and activate them at the frame you want the glass to break.

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. Have a look at Blenderguru's shattered glass tutorial, and add an image texture to your glass. https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-glass-smash-animation